# How to update a ecs service using nodejs API?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I would like to update the desired, min and max count of the ECS service API using nodejs (rather than python as stated below, source: aws sample)

```py
import boto3
def handler(event, context):
    ecsregion = event['region']
    cluster_name = event['cluster']
    service_name = event['service']
    task_count = event['taskCount']
    ecs_client = boto3.client('ecs', region_name=ecsregion)
    response=ecs_client.update_service(cluster=cluster_name, service=service_name, desiredCount=int(task_count))
    print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found a partial answer from the AWS Source. Let me use this and will get back if I stuck again.

```
/* This example updates the desired count of the my-http-service service to 10. */

 var params = {
  desiredCount: 10, 
  service: "my-http-service"
 };
 ecs.updateService(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else     console.log(data);           // successful response
   /*
   data = {
   }
   */
 });
```